# pyopengl shader warning/info confusion over chose alternate

Tags: pyopengl

I have a small pyopengl piece of code that uses shaders.  I get the following "info" log messages but have no idea what they mean and the documentation is poor -- or I could not find it.

Anyone could clarify what those mean?

```
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  OpenGL Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.59
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glCreateShader from glCreateShader, glCreateShaderObjectARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glShaderSource from glShaderSource, glShaderSourceARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glCompileShader from glCompileShader, glCompileShaderARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glGetShaderiv from glGetShaderiv, glGetObjectParameterivARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glCreateProgram from glCreateProgram, glCreateProgramObjectARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glAttachShader from glAttachShader, glAttachObjectARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glLinkProgram from glLinkProgram, glLinkProgramARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glValidateProgram from glValidateProgram, glValidateProgramARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glGetProgramiv from glGetProgramiv, glGetObjectParameterivARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glDeleteShader from glDeleteShader, glDeleteObjectARB
INFO     [   MainThread::OpenGL.extensions]  Chose alternate: glUseProgram from glUseProgram, glUseProgramObjectARB
```

The import lines are:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL.ARB.shader_objects import *
from OpenGL.GL.ARB.fragment_shader import *
from OpenGL.GL.ARB.vertex_shader import *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyOpenGL can choose between the core GLSL versions of shader functions and their NVIDIA ARB equivalents if both are available.  Your info log is telling you that your program chose the core versions when given a choice.

Comment: How can I set it a switch to use either the core or the NVIDIA ARB versions?

Comment: @Sardathrion something like `from OpenGL.GL.ARB.shader_objects import *` check out http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ctypes/using.html

Comment: With the import lines as above, I am still getting those info messages.  Any idea why it pick the core ones instead of the ARB ones?

Comment: I'm guessing where the functionality is available in the core library then it will choose that option.  The extensions are really for functions that aren't supported in the core library for a given version/platform.

Comment: And lastly... Which one are more optimised:  The core ones or the NVIDIA ones?  Or is this a length of string (the yarn string, not a character string ^_~) type of question...